# PyQGIS: ERROR 1: A file system object called 'memory.gpkg' already exists

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm iterating multiple shapefiles in a folder. On each I want to

1. Apply 'dissolve' with a memory layer as output,
2. Create an in-memory spatial index for the memory layer,
3. Apply multiparts-to-singlepart with a shape as output and
4. Create a qix file for each shape.

However, while the first iteration doesnt't create a problem, so the first shapefile seems to be created as I want to, when the same processes are applied on the the second shapefile I get the error 'A file system object called 'memory.gpkg' already exists.'.

The problem seems to be in the creation of the memory layer when the dissolve function is applied.

This is the error:

[image]

This is the code:

```
def diss(inputfolderpath, outputfolderpath):
    for filename in os.listdir(inputfolderpath):
        if '.shp' in filename:
     
            shapefilepath = inputfolderpath + '/' + filename
            outputfilepath = outputfolderpath +'/' + filename
            

            ### DISSOLVE
            dissolved = processing.run("native:dissolve",{'INPUT':shapefilepath,
                                             'FIELD':['fclass', 'maxspeed', 'bridge', 'tunnel'],
                                             'OUTPUT':'memory'}
                            )

            # Get dissolve layer as memory layer
            dissolve_layer = dissolved['OUTPUT']
            
            # Create qgs vector layer from memory layer
            dlayer = QgsVectorLayer(dissolve_layer, 'layer_name', 'ogr')

            # Check if qgs layer is valid
            if not dlayer.isValid():
                print("Layer failed to load!")
                print('------------')
            else:
            # Create in-memory spatial index
                QgsSpatialIndex(dlayer.getFeatures())
                print(f'spatial index set for {filename}')


            #### MULTIPART TO SINGLEPARTS
            multiparttosingleparts = processing.run("qgis:multiparttosingleparts", {'INPUT': dlayer,
                                                                                    'OUTPUT': outputfilepath})
            print(f'{filename} to singlepart ok')

            layer_singleparts = multiparttosingleparts['OUTPUT']
            print(f'set spatial index set singlepart {filename}')
            vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(layer_singleparts, 'layer_name', 'ogr')

            if not vlayer.isValid():
                print("Layer failed to load!")
                print(outputfilepath)
                print('------------')
            else:
                # This creates a spatial index as a qix-file
                vlayer.dataProvider().createSpatialIndex()
                print(outputfilepath)
                print('OK')
                print('------------')
```

What am I doing wrong?

QGIS 3.28 'Firenze'
Windows 10

Comment: Please place error messages in the Question body as text. Images are not legible on all devices and cannot be searched by others to locate the Answer.

Comment: Ok, I will do it the next time!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a memory layer, then you are missing a "`:`". Use  `'OUTPUT': 'memory:'` or `'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT`.

Right now your code is creating a file called "memory.gpkg" in your working directory.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it afterwards, that I created a bunch of temporary layer. However, as the result was correct, I was satisfied with it for now. Still, when I used `OUTPUT: 'memory:'`I also got an error (unfortunately I don't know `what error). So, next time I would try to use ```'OUTPUT':'f{filename}:'``` to create a memory layer with a name. Is that correct?

Comment: No, if you are happy with the current code, just use it. :) `"f{filename}:"` would fail if you are on Windows because ":" is not allowed in filenames. `"memory:"` is a special string for QGIS that will lead to the creation of a layer that is stored purely in RAM, not as an actual file.

Comment: Ah, okay, thank you for the information! Mh, do you have an idea why the code then didn't work when I tried adding ```'OUTPUT':'memory:'``` ? Of course it would be nicer to just create in-memory layer instead of temp layer, as I had to manually delete the temp layer from my PyCharm project afterwards.

Comment: I see nothing super obvious, maybe something with the spatial indexing stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this discussion about [temporary layers with a name getting dropped into bin-directory](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19637) I gave a name to the temporary layer by adding `'OUTPUT':f'{filename}'` instead of `'OUTPUT':'memory'`.However, this will not create an in-memory layer, but a temporary layer in the folder your script is located. See @bugmenot123 answer for creating an in-memory layer.